# Parse React Error On Facebook Login

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, reactjs, parse-react

I am learning Parse together with React. So far I have in my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="http://fb.me/react-0.13.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-react.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <title>Learning Parse</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>From CloudCode hosting</h1>

    <a href="#" id="btn-fb-login">Login with Facebook</a>
    <a href="#" id="btn-logout">Logout</a>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And in my JS

```
document.getElementById('btn-fb-login').addEventListener('click', function() {
  Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn('public_profile,email', {
    success: function(user) {
      console.log('logged in as', user);
    },
    error: function(user, err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  });
});
```

Problem is when I login, it works but I see an error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Parse.User._saveCurrentUser is not a function
```

Why is that? I have yet to do anything React specific, just simple DOM events so far